# Have Pivot Table rows sort so that it matches value in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, synchronization, pivot-table

I have:

- A table that contains a list of promotions and their start and end date that I will constantly add to over time
- A Pivot Table that is built from combining that table with a SQL query to get the sales results

[image: Starting Table and Pivot Table]

I would like it so that no matter how the table is sorted, the Pivot table will sort so that the rows match based on the Promo, ID and Start and End dates

[image: Desired Results]

Is this possible either just in excel or with VBA (of which I  have no training in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I would recommend to store these two tables separately (or at least the SQL one) and then have a separate "View" worksheet with a lookup function for SQL table rows that you want joined to the first table.

This will it will be much less of a pain to maintain and you don't even need VBA. Just a VLOOKUP function.